# Building virt-viewer on CentOS failed

Tags: linux, centos, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, virt-manager

When I have attempted to build `virt-viewer` 0.2.x on CentOS, I had a build problem:

```
virt_viewer-viewer.o: In function `viewer_resize_main_window':
/root/virt/virt-viewer-0.2.0/src/viewer.c:285: undefined reference to `gtk_widget_get_window'
/root/virt/virt-viewer-0.2.0/src/viewer.c:286: undefined reference to `gtk_widget_get_window'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [virt-viewer] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/virt/virt-viewer-0.2.0/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/virt/virt-viewer-0.2.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I've unsuccessfully studied many Google-related sources. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing following packages using :

```
$ yum install gtk+-devel
$ yum install xulrunner-devel
```

Comment: I try it, but these packages already installed

Comment: Rebuilt attempt with make clean then ./configure will no effect

Comment: Try the second one. Have you already installed xulrunner-devel? Also, you tried gtk+-devel, not just gtk+, right?

Comment: Already installed

Comment: 1.9.2.13 centos v. 5.5

Comment: # uname -a
Linux XXXXXXX 2.6.18-194.32.1.el5 #1 SMP Wed Jan 5 17:52:25 EST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I've all tries about your suggestions

Comment: all packages - gtk+* is already installed

Comment: Hmm. I'm at a loss then. If I find anything I'll post here.

Comment: [root@ip11 virt-viewer-0.2.0]# yum list gtk+*
Loaded plugins: changelog, fastestmirror, kernel-module
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Installed Packages
gtk+.i386                           1:1.2.10-56.el5                    installed
gtk+.x86_64                         1:1.2.10-56.el5                    installed
gtk+-devel.i386                     1:1.2.10-56.el5                    installed
gtk+-devel.x86_64                   1:1.2.10-56.el5                    installed

Comment: as root, run `/sbin/ldconfig`

Comment: any options or actons?

Comment: without options - further build is unsuccessful

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to compile under CentOS 5.5 but I [downloaded version 0.3.1](http://virt-manager.org/download/sources/virt-viewer/virt-viewer-0.3.1.tar.gz) which is the latest release. I had to comment out line 135 in src/display-vnc.c:

`/* gdk_window_beep(GTK_WIDGET(viewer->window)->window); */`

or you get:

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/virt-viewer-0.3.1/src'
  CC     virt_viewer-display-vnc.o
display-vnc.c: In function ‘viewer_bell’:
display-vnc.c:135: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gtk_window_beep’
display-vnc.c:135: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘gtk_window_beep’
  CCLD   virt-viewer
virt_viewer-display-vnc.o: In function `viewer_bell':
```

This gave me a working virt-viewer, but I have no way to test this:

```
# src/virt-viewer -V
virt-viewer version 0.3.1
```

[This](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.emulators.virt-tools/1006) and [this](http://hg.fedorahosted.org/hg/virt-manager/rev/7b6f5d8bed5d) seem very relevant. Hope this helps.

[Announcement](https://www.redhat.com/archives/virt-tools-list/2011-February/msg00116.html) on the 0.3.1 release.

Comment: Also, I had to install libglade2-devel and some other devel packages using yum from the standard CentOS repo.

Comment: I did it, build successful

Comment: But, when I click on VM and go ti's properties, I've received run-time error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/virtinst/VirtualVideoDevice.py", line 33, in __init__
    parsexml, parsexmlnode, caps)
TypeError: __init__() takes at most 2 arguments (5 given)
Please assist, how to solve this problem?